# how to transfer dot in mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to design a RewriteRule for the URL `beta2.0/user/11`  to `beta2.0/user.php?11`  and my .htaccess rule is

```
RewriteRule ^beta2\.0/user/([0-9]*)$ /beta2.0/user.php?user_id=$1 [L]
```

however the RewriteRule not work, is there any problem in my Rule? And the problem is in the dot in the original url

Comment: Are you using this in an htaccess or  in server.config file?

Comment: @starkeen in an htaccess and I'm sure the problem is about the . (dot)

Comment: What error do you get when you go to `example. com/beta2.0/user/11` ?

Comment: @starkeen there is no any error.. just not work

Answer (score 1):

I assume your .htaccess is located in the same level as beta2.0 directory.

```
root
   +---.htaccess
   +--- beta2.0/
              +---user.php
```

Place the following into .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule beta2\.0/user/([0-9]+) "/beta2.0/user.php?user_id=$1"
```

Comment: However it's still not working to my condition. -_-

Comment: When I remove the dot (just 20 not 2.0) it's working correctly , however , as I add the dot to 2.0 it's not working...